# PHP ldap_connect to multiple hosts in case of one beeing not reachable

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

A co-worker suggested that we use multiple hosts for a website where authentication
is based on LDAP in case one host is currently down.  Now I know you can do something like

```
$LDAP_SERVERS = "10.101.01.1 10.100.10.2";
$ldap = ldap_connect($LDAP_SERVERS);
```

But I'm using an config file:

```
return [
    'domain_controller' => ['10.101.01.1', '10.100.10.2'],
    'base_dn'           => 'OU=foo,DC=example,DC=local',
    'ssl'               => false,
    ...
];
```

Whereas my connection is done via

```
$protocol = $this->ssl ? $this::PROTOCOL_SSL : $this::PROTOCOL;
$port     = $this->ssl ? $this::PORT_SSL : $this::PORT;

return $this->connection = ldap_connect($protocol . $hostname, $port);
```

As the co-worker suggested it might be possible that our LDAP hosts will run via SSL in the future, how can I make this multiple hosts work for this? Above it's working with the hostname only, but that's because it's non-ssl based. Given SSL you need the *ldaps://* protocol and the portnumber, right?
Therefore it would not work with the hostname only and I'm not sure if you can do something as simple that the connection looks like
`ldap_connect('ldaps://' . '10.101.01.1 10.100.10.2', 123);`
(supposed both servers run the same port for ssl based ldap)

**EDIT:** Got it working by using `ldap_connect('ldaps://hostnameone ldaps://hostnametwo, 636');` As a reddit user said: "*Notice they are still separated by spaces, and should be tried in order of appearance..*"

Comment: If you use an URI you can omit the port-number as it will not be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
ldap_connect("ldaps://example.com:389 ldap://example.com:389")
```

But beware: This will on starting the connection (which is **not** on calling `ldap_connect`) try the first server and **after a timeout** try the next server and so on. This might cause an unwanted delay!

Answer (score -1):

PHPs ldap_connect() will return false if the connection can not be made.
More on [ldap_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php)

Try something like this:

```
if(!$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($adhost1)) {
    if(!$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($adhost2)) {
        die('Unable to establish LDAP connection.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be pretty bad in case of performance? Let's say the config file has 5 hosts and it's a bad day where 4 of them are down. So it'd have to run a recursive loop for find the one working. And this step would be repeated for every webpage since there's no real *static* in PHP?

Comment: You could store connection statuses in MySql  and pull them in order from working to not working. That it is more likely to have a working one first and update the table if status of a host changes. That way it would only br slow once if servers went down.

Comment: ```ldap_connect``` returns false if the URI doesn't seem to be correct! It does not connect (even though it looks like it would) and therefore connection issues will surface on the first bind! Therefore this will **not** work as you expect it!